# Бывший химик и диссидент - можно ли считать однородными членами?

Tags: однородные-члены

Химик - специальность, диссидент - инакомы́слящий — человек. Можно ли написать так: бывший химик и диссидент Иванов, если Иванов и бывший химик, и диссидент.

Или правильно только так: бывший химик диссидент Иванов?

Answer (score 2):

***Бывший химик и диссидент.***

Это **однородные члены со сближенными значениями,** которые обозначают характеристику лица (это их общая тема).

Они **не могут находиться в неоднородных отношениях**, так как слово ***диссидент*** имеет оценочное значение. Точно также всегда однородны **художественные определения,** например: *тяжелые, свинцовые тучи.*

Если мы будем считать приложения неоднородными, то получится ***диссидент Иванов***, который был химиком. Но диссидент – это **не должность, не профессия, не постоянное свойство.** Это оценка, данная человеку со стороны какой-то группы лиц. Для одних он диссидент, а для других нет.

Указанные приложения раскрывают определенные черты характера человека, а это **однородные признаки.**

Примеры **неоднородных** приложений: *заведующий кафедрой профессор Сорокин, генеральный директор производственного объединения кандидат технических наук Петров, мой друг художник Волков.*

Answer (score 1):

Первое ("бывший химик и диссидент") лучше. Это может показаться странным, но на самом деле в установлении однородности членов последнее слово всегда остается за автором.
Хотя по внешним признакам тут скорее именно однородные, но контекста маловато.

Но здесь другое. Диссидент - он тоже "бывший"? Если да, то
***бывший химик и бывший диссидент Иванов.***
Тут уж без союза (или запятой) просто не обойтись.
А если диссидент он действующий, то тем более:
***бывший химик и всё еще диссидент Иванов.***

Ну или местами поменять.

> Химик он бывший, а когда перестал работать химиком, стал диссидентом.

Тогда еще веселее. Если читатель не введен в курс дела предыдущим текстом, то рекомендую
***ставший диссидентом бывший химик Иванов.***
Желательное именно в таком порядке: подчеркивая интересующую вас неоднородность. 
Иное (*бывший химик ставший ныне диссидентом Иванов.*) - на мой вкус хуже.

Comment: Химик он бывший, а когда перестал работать химиком, стал диссидентом.